# How does one enable Age Gating in Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I want to explore using Age Gating in Azure AD B2C.  What do I need to do to access Age Gating related settings in the Azure portal?

I've read the article at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/basic-age-gating, however the instructions contained therein do not seem to apply to my Azure AD B2C tenant or workflows, as I can only get as far as "Step 2.[...] search for and select Azure AD B2C".  Once I do this, there is no "Properties" to select.
I believe I've searched through all relevant pages in the azure portal and cannot find any mention of Age Gating.

Possibly related: I can see the "Legal Age Group Classification" user attribute in the overall user attribute list, but it does not appear as an option to select under the sign up/sign in workflow user attribute list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mine also was not showing at first, but when I clicked the link "Try the age gating preview" under the "What's new" section, the properties blade appeared. 
[image]

After selecting the link you should be able to see the Age Gating configuration options in the Properties blade.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's it!  Not sure how I didn't see that link hanging out under news; guess it was where I least expected.  Thank you!!

Comment: @MarileeTurscakmsft age gating is still in public preview since you answered/questioned in 2019, I wanted to know if everything is working fine or if you have experienced any issues.